# Как задать ширину создаваемому элементу с помощью createElement

Tags: javascript

При создание дивов их область занимает всю ширину field, и следующий элемент попадает на следующую строку, а я хочу расположить их друг за другом. Как это сделать?

JS:

```
    var newDiv = null;

    for(var i = 0; i<2;i++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class=target></div>";
        field.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
```

CSS:

```
#field{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.target{
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 2px;    
    width: 94px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проста задать `display:flex` идентификатору `field`

```js
var newDiv = null;

for(var i = 0; i<2;i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class=target></div>";
    field.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```css
#field{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:flex; //Только это строка добавлено
}
.target{
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 2px;    
    width: 94px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="field"></div>
```